# Color nuance problems when converting PDF to JPG with PHP Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I'm experiencing a nuance color change when converting PDF's to JPG's only on certain PDF files. Actually the problematic files are only 2 (out of many), and the nuance change is only on the blue color (from #2a447a to #0630e4, or from #00a4d6 to #00ffff).

The conversion process is pretty much straightforward:

```
$im = new \Imagick();
$im->setResolution(200, 200);
$im->readImage($path . $this->filename);

$im->trimImage(0);
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$im->setImageCompression(\Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);

$im->stripImage();

$tmpFile = sys_get_temp_dir() . '/' . $this->cleanUpImageName($this->label) . '.jpg';
$im->writeImage($tmpFile);

$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

PHP version is 5.4.36, Imagick is 6.6.0-4

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=27685 and http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecolorspace.php

Comment: 6.6.0-4 is quite an old version of ImageMagick. If possible, maybe try a newer version. Otherwise can you post an example image?

Comment: Updating the ghostscript fixed the issue. Thanks user5542121. You can put it as an answer, so I could accept it as best answer.